# print all the content in a "node list" on the same line

Tags: java, printing, nodes

I´m a beginner and I'm working with java currently, I need to write in a single line an equation like 5x^3 + 2x^4 + ... using the content inside nodes.

Here is my class Node:

```java
public class Node {
    private Termo element;
    private Node next;
    
    public Node(){
        element = null;
        next= null;
    }
    
    public Node( Termo element, Node next){
        this.element= element;
        this.next= next;
    }
    
     public void setnext( Node next){
        this.next= next;
    }
    
    public Node getnext(){
        return proximo;
    } 
    
     public void setElement( Termo element){
        this.element= element;
    }
    
    public Termo getElement(){
        return element;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Termo: " + getElement().getCoef() + "x^" +getElement().getExp();
    }
}
```

My class Termo (which is an object with the coefficient and the exponent)

```
private double coef;
private int exp;

public Termo() {
    coef=0;
    exp=0;
}

public Termo(double coef, int exp) {
    this.coef = coef;
    this.exp = exp;
}

public double  getCoef() {
    return coef;
}

public void setCoef(int coef) {
    this.coef = coef;
}

public int getExp() {
    return exp;
}

public void setExp(int exp) {
    this.exp = exp;
}

public Object getObject(){
    Termo obj = new Termo(this.coef, this.exp);
    return obj;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return coef + " " + exp;
}
```

I created this method to print the content , but i want it in a single line:

```
public void escrevePolinomio (Node lista){
        if(lista != null){
            System.out.println(lista.getElement().getCoef()+"x^"+lista.getElement().getExp());
            lista=lista.getnext();
            escrevePolinomio(lista);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `System.out.print()` instead of `System.out.println()`:

```java
public void escrevePolinomio (Node lista){
    if(lista != null){
        System.out.print(lista.getElement().getCoef()+"x^"+lista.getElement().getExp());
        lista=lista.getnext();
        escrevePolinomio(lista);
    }
}
```